# what permissions are needed to give a role ability to access: admin/content list page

Tags: 7

what permission do i need to give a role to give them access to the list page of content. path: admin/content

This is for drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

found it! its under this:

```
Access the content overview page
Get an overview of all content.
```